# Simple but interesting math puzzle

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Four numbers are available: $1$, $3$, $4$ and $6$. Every number must be used once and only once with (some of) the operations $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$ to form the number $24$.

It's from the book "Art of Exploitation", 2nd edition. Give it a try!

Comment: Do we have to use every number? Otherwise 6 * 4...

Comment: Yes, every number need to be used only once.

Comment: can you confirm if writing ** or ++ is ok?

Comment: no it is not okay, you can only use +, -, * and / once at time.

Answer (score 20):

An answer to this problem is:

> $6 \div (1 - \frac34)$

Comment: Great first answer and welcome to puzzling.stackexchange. It is customary to hide answers by using the spoiler tag >! to give others a chance to solve it on their own.

Answer (score 1):

A possible interpretation of the rules:

> $1+3+4+6=24_{5}$

Answer (score -2):

Another possible answer could be...

> $(14-6) \times 3 = 24$

Comment: the problems says the NUMBERS 1,3,4, and 6, not the DIGITS 1,3,4, and 6

Answer (score -3):

Bit of an off the wall answer

> (6-4)(3+1) **forms** 24 if you calculate the values within the brackets, and leave the results as they are

Not mathematically correct at all I know, it's an answer that loosely fits the wording of the puzzle

Answer (score -4):

Answer could also b:

> $6 \times 4 \times 1^3$

Comment: Exponents weren't allowed in the puzzle

Comment: where does it say that? I would write a little 3 without the '^' but don't know how to here....

Comment: The question states the operators you can use are +, -, * and /

Comment: I understand - but would it not be correct to write 1(little 3) and I would avoid the exponent operator? I have totally no idea if that makes sense (I'm not great in the math department) please explain...

Comment: Doesn't matter if you write multiplication as 3 x 4, or 3 * 4, they both equal 12. The operation is the same, and that's what's limited in the puzzle

Comment: @Lynch in python you can do power function by doing `**` and as `*` is allowed, and there is no specify notation

Comment: In PHP, and other languages, you can use ++ to increment a number. But neither ** nor ++ were specified as operators. I could be wrong of course, we'll have to wait for OP to confirm

Comment: @user902383 I would argue even though both operators ** and * use the same characters, they are very different operators, and it is not at all clear you may combine the characters to a new operator.